# Can Javascript's Date().getTime() be incorrect if the system clock is wrong?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Occasionally we get a report from users that a countdown timer in our application is set too high, or is displaying negative numbers. I figured it was a timezone issue but I've been unable to replicate it by changing my clock settings - even if I change the ones in my computer's BIOS. The only way I was able to replicate it was by actually adding or subtracting 3600 seconds from the timestamp in my code.

I read that `Date().getTime()` always provides a UTC timestamp. I doubt it's sourced from the internet, so it makes sense to me that it could be wrong if the computer is providing an incorrect time. Unfortunately I can't make this actually happen yet.

I also can't find much information online about this, or gather any data from our users (This is very infrequent and they unsurprisingly become unwilling to help once I mention timezones and system clocks).

So, can Javascript provide me with an incorrect UTC timestamp? If so, is there a strategy to ensure the timestamp is accurate?

Edit -
It struck me that the simplest solution is probably just to send over the server time and use that, since it doesn't need to be especially accurate.

Comment: if the system clock is wrong then its wrong.

Comment: Yes Date() uses the system clock. If the clock is wrong, Date() will be wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any other patterns occuring with this issue - are all the reporting users actually in the same time zone or are they using the same browser?

Comment: @DanielA.White I began to doubt this conclusion, since both the clocks on my system are wrong (in different ways) right now, but I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RoboBear Unfortunately I didn't have the opportunity to collect any metrics. We did ask a few people to help but got no response (this is via email support).

Comment: did you restart the browser after setting the wrong time?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, and tried different browsers and restarting the machine completely too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say if you want to dig into implementation - go and check Mozilla code. It's open source. I dig into it because of your post and I finally reach to the file: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/vm/Time.cpp

It has some interesting function called `NowCalibrate()`. Seems that it's doing the trick with fixing time if the system time is off or something. 
You can check lines 79 to 140. I will attach portion of the code that initializes the time.

```
void
PRMJ_NowInit()
{
    memset(&calibration, 0, sizeof(calibration));

    // According to the documentation, QueryPerformanceFrequency will never
    // return false or return a non-zero frequency on systems that run
    // Windows XP or later. Also, the frequency is fixed so we only have to
    // query it once.
    LARGE_INTEGER liFreq;
    DebugOnly<BOOL> res = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liFreq);
    MOZ_ASSERT(res);
    calibration.freq = double(liFreq.QuadPart);
    MOZ_ASSERT(calibration.freq > 0.0);

    InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&calibration.data_lock, DataLockSpinCount);

    // Windows 8 has a new API function we can use.
    if (HMODULE h = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll")) {
        pGetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime =
            (void (WINAPI*)(LPFILETIME))GetProcAddress(h, "GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime");
    }
}
```

On the other side I found that every other browser has it's own implementation, but Mozilla can be a real world example of how the initial time can be calculated and calibrated after certain period.